# Can detect magic detect psionic effects?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

In Pathfinder Psionics, the standard rule is that magic and psionics are more or less the same.  `Spell Resistance` is also `Power Resistance` and so forth.

Can `Detect Magic` detect a n active psionic effect?  If so, can it be used to identify the effect?  If it can be used to identify, does a `Spell Craft` check suffice, or is a `Psi Craft` check required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Paizo has studiously avoided publishing a single official word on psionics. The only psionics rules are from a third party, Dreamscarred Press, but are in the online Pathfinder SRD.  [According to those rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers), if you are using magic-psionics transparency, then you treat powers just like spells or spell-like abilities, so yes, detect magic would detect and identify them. The question reduces to "How does that work with a spell-like ability?" Transparency means "the same" so yes. Spellcraft would let you ID a power as it was being used; Detect Magic would identify an active power's school (note those are two different things). If you use magic-psi transparency then psi is magic and all the same rules apply.

They include the separate PsiCraft skill because you don't have to use "magic-psionics transparency". That's just the default. A GM could, if they wanted, make them opaque to each other, at which point a Psicraft skill is necessary. Also because some classes might have Psicraft as a class skill that don't have Spellcraft.

Comment: It’s worth noting that **not** using Magic-Psionics Transparency tends to work really poorly unless you do a lot of careful consideration of how that will work, and none of the authors of 3.x psionics (Wizards of the Coast, Bruce Cordel’s indy publishing, or Dreamscarred Press) recommends it.